# Unable to load Codeigniter website

Tags: php, codeigniter

when I pointed it to the root of the website. Its showing the below error
[image]

Comment: http://woodpeck3r.com/quizoh/

Comment: What are you trying to do in the constructor and index function of your default controller?

Comment: well, the error isn't really that informative, but check your controller and view, it says 'Undefined variable: mimes' look for that in your code

Comment: If you view the source there is an error `Call to undefined function base_url()`. Make sure you're the loading to URL helper to use this function.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wCkDCDPD

Comment: Awesome @Lefters Its working now but still cant get rid of the PHP errors..

Comment: I ran into this same error. In mine it was caused from upgrading from 2.2 to 3.0 incorrectly. I redid the upgrade by downloading the directly from github and made the modifications and the error went away.